# salary calculator not working

Tags: bug, salary-calculator, bug-reporting-process

Salary calculator doesn't work? I tried in multiple browsers, when you click 'calculate salary' it just refreshes the page but does not show the salary nor an error message.

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep over it, it was pretty inaccurate when I last tried it. You could just take your current salary and multiply it with a random number between 1.5 and 2 and get the answer they would give you... Why? Because based on their data set, it's likely to tell you that you're underpaid before directing you towards jobs where you could earn more.